# TypeError: Error multiplying a term outside of integration by the integrated function

Tags: python, types, numerical-integration

I have this Python code below and it gives me the error,

```
Q, err =((4*n_f*k_avg*l_f)/(visc_f*mat.tan(alpha)))*quad(integrand, r_w, h_f)

can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'.
```

I have tried different work arounds but i just cant figure out what the problem is.

```
import math as mat
import scipy.special as sp
from scipy.integrate import quad
```

Data

```
k_h     = 0.001     
k_v     = 0.0002   
visc_f  = 0.5       
B_o     = 1.25      
r_w     = 9.997    
n_f     = 4         
l_f     = 3048      
h_f     = 914.4     
w       = 0.635     
k_f     = 50        
p_e     = 340.23    
p_w     = 272.18
```

computing constants

```
k_avg = mat.sqrt(k_h*k_v) 

alpha = mat.pi/n_f

pd = p_e - p_w

c = (4*k_avg*l_f)/(w*k_f*mat.tan(alpha))

T_01 = mat.sqrt(r_w)*sp.i1(2*mat.sqrt(c)*mat.sqrt(r_w)) 


T_02 = mat.sqrt(r_w)*sp.k1(2*mat.sqrt(c)*mat.sqrt(r_w))


T_11 = mat.sqrt(h_f)*sp.i1(2*mat.sqrt(c)*mat.sqrt(h_f))

T_12 = mat.sqrt(h_f)*sp.k1(2*mat.sqrt(c)*mat.sqrt(h_f))

C_1 = (pd*T_12)/(T_02*T_11-T_12*T_01)

C_2 = (pd*T_11)/(T_02*T_11-T_12*T_01)
```

performing Integration

```
def integrand(x):
    return C_1*mat.sqrt(x)*sp.i1(2*mat.sqrt(c)*mat.sqrt(x))\
       +C_2*mat.sqrt(x)*sp.k1(2*mat.sqrt(c)*mat.sqrt(x))/x 
Q, err =((4*n_f*k_avg*l_f)/(visc_f*mat.tan(alpha)))*quad(integrand, r_w, h_f)

print(Q)
```

Comment: it's probably automatically setting `k_f` and `n_f` as `int`... try `n_f = float(4)` and `k_f = float(50)`